# Combine rows in same column and table with similar values and sum values

Tags: sql

I have very large data set as below (example) :

```
#ID  #report_name           #report_count 
1     ReportA1              3
2     ReportA1(PDF)         4
3     ReportA2              2
4     ReportA2(PDF)         6
5     ReportA3              7
6     ReportA3(PDF)         2
7     ReportA4              9   
8     ReportA4(PDF)         7
9     ReportA5              1
10    ReportA5(PDF)         2
11    ReportA6              8
12    ReportA6(PDF)         9
13    ReportA7              8
14    ReportA7(PDF)         6
15    ReportA8              6
16    ReportA8(PDF)         7
17    ReportA9              5
18    ReportA9(PDF)         9
19    ReportA10             7
20    ReportA10(PDF)        1
```

I want to make **SQL query** so that i can **merge two rows as single rows**.

For example ReportA1 and ReportA1(PDF) as ReportA1.

My Question, how to create SQL statement to combine two rows of data (i.e ReportA1 and ReportA1(PDF)) 
and count it as single name (i.e ReportA1) as table below (example only) ?

```
#ID  #report_name   #report_count       
1   ReportA1        7
2   ReportA2        8
3   ReportA3        9
4   ReportA4        16
5   ReportA5        3
6   ReportA6        17
7   ReportA7        14
8   ReportA8        13
9   ReportA9        14
10  ReportA10       8
```

Comment: MSSQL, MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mySQL you can probably do this:

```
SELECT ReportName, SUM(ReportCount) as ReportsCount 
FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(ReportName,'(PDF)','') as ReportName, ReportCount
  FROM Reports ) T
GROUP BY ReportName
```

See <kbd>[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be7d6/1)</kbd>

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, use single quotes for string literals, e.g. '(PDF)'. (Still the best answer!)

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. I will modify according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
select substr(report_name,8),sum(report_count) from yourtablename
groupb by (substr(report_name,8))
```

This is Oracle Syntax, but every SQL dialekt have a "substr" methode.

Answer (score 0):

I consider report_name field always differ by "(pdf)" word in each two rows. If that's the case then you can try out following:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by replace(report_name, '(pdf)', '')) as ID, 
replace(report_name, '(pdf)', '') as report_name, sum(report_count) as report_count
FRom @temp
Group by replace(report_name, '(pdf)', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example that would help you:**

```
SELECT
    report_name,
    report_count
FROM
(
    SELECT REPLACE(report_name, '(PDF)') AS report_name, SUM(report_count) AS report_count FROM
    (
        SELECT 'RPT A1(PDF)' AS report_name, 4 AS report_count FROM DUAL
         UNION
        SELECT 'RPT A1' AS report_name, 3 AS report_count FROM DUAL
         UNION
        SELECT 'RPT A2(PDF)' AS report_name, 12 AS report_count FROM DUAL
         UNION
        SELECT 'RPT A2' AS report_name, 5 AS report_count FROM DUAL
         UNION
        SELECT 'RPT A3(PDF)' AS report_name, 8 AS report_count FROM DUAL
         UNION
        SELECT 'RPT A3' AS report_name, 2 AS report_count FROM DUAL
    )
    GROUP BY REPLACE(report_name, '(PDF)')
)
ORDER BY report_name
```

**This example output is:**

```
RPT A1  7
RPT A2  17
RPT A3  10
```

**Summary:**

using Group by `GROUP BY REPLACE(report_name, '(PDF)')` will remove the word **(PDF)** from the `report_name` column and group by the result of the `REPLACE` function

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server:

```
SELECT RName AS 'report_name', SUM(report_count) AS 'report_count'
FROM(
    SELECT REPLACE(report_name,'(PDF)','') AS 'RName' 
           ,report_count 
    FROM dbo.test)
GROUP BY [RName]
```

This should work